# The woocommerce cart always comes up empty in my gatsby graphql

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, graphql, gatsby, woocommerce-rest-api

Its my first question, hope I am doing it right. I am trying to make a gatsby frontend for my woocommerce and its all fine. Up untill now all my queries has worked just fine, but when I make a query to get the cart information, it always comes up empty on my localhost://8000/___graphql but in the wp graphiql i can see it just fine.

here is my gatsby-config I guess this is where the problem would be.

```
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "shopone",
  },  
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        url:
          process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL ||
          `https://wpurl/graphql`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "WPGraphQL",
        fieldName: "wpcontent",
        url: "https://wpurl/graphql",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images',
      options: {
        wordPressUrl: 'https://my/wpurl/',
        uploadsUrl: 'https://my/url/wp-content/uploads/',
        processPostTypes: ['Page', 'Post', 'CustomPost'],
        graphqlTypeName: 'WPGraphQL',
        httpHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
        }
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: (__dirname, `src`),
      }, 
    },
      `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, 
      `gatsby-plugin-sharp`
  ],
};
```

Comment: dynamic parts (real/life WP API) vs static/pregenerated parts (Gatsby processed WP API) ... read gatsby docs about `build time vs runtime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `localhost:8000/___graphql` is generated on the build-time, at this point, the cart will be always empty since the user has not been allowed to fill it yet.

Your WP GraphiQL API is an asynchronous API that gets the data in real-time, on-demand as the user fills the cart so it will always contain the as soon as the requests are done. To "connect" both, you will need to perform some fetch/post request to your API.

You can read for further information in [Build Time and Client Runtime Data Fetching](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/).